# Kotlin Exposed SELECT single record

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

is there any way to select only one record with kotlin exposed?
Currently I'm using below code to select a user from DB, but is there any function like selectSingle() to get an object (not list) ?

```
fun getUser(userId: Int): User? {

    var user: User? = null

    transaction {
        user = UserTable.select { UserTable.id eq userId }.limit(1).map { User.fromRow(it) }[0]
    }

    return user
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good solution for this. Credits goes to [hfazai](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1111#issuecomment-738871735)

```
fun getUser(userId: Int): User? {

var user: User? = null

val user = transaction {
   user = UserTable.select { UserTable.id eq userId }.limit(1).single().let { User.fromRow(it) }
}

return user
}
```

PS : single() will throw NoSuchElementException if there is no result and IllegalArgumentException if there is more than one resulted row.

also you can ommit the user variable

```
fun getUser(userId: Int): User = 
        transaction {
                UserTable.select { UserTable.id eq userId }.limit(1).single().let { User.fromRow(it) }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way then what you already do. You can use `first()` or `firstOrNull` instead of `[0]`.

As always with Kotlin, you can create your own extension to simplify the calls:

```
fun Query.selectSingle() = limit(1).firstOrNull()
```

In a special case when you fetch the objects by their primary key, you can use DAO's `findById` ([docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#read)).
Using DAOs gives you the additional benefit of `wrapRow`/`wrapRows` ([usage example](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/404#issuecomment-552227768)) implementation which, I would guess, works similar to `User.fromRow(it)` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ali's answer since I cannot post a comment. You can now use `singleOrNull` to avoid NoSuchElementException when there's no result.

```
fun getUser(userId: Int): User = 
    transaction {
        UserTable.select { 
            UserTable.id eq userId 
        }.limit(1).singleOrNull()?.let { User.fromRow(it) }
    }
```